# C# MVC 5 routing

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, routes

I hope you can help me :)
I'm trying to do a logoff function in my .net mvc app, but links that I make never reach le right route. Here is my code :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        Session[UserSessionIdentifier] = null;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    @Html.ActionLink("Log off", "LogOff", "Account")
```

When I click on this link, I had this url in my browser :

```
http://localhost:52041/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogOff
```

Where is my error ?

Comment: Have you activated `AuthorizeAttribute` in the controller? Sounds like you should mark `LogOff` action with `[AllowAnonymous]` after destroying logged off user's session data.

Comment: Ok, I had a [Authorize] attribute on my class, that's why ! Allow [AllowAnonymous] on LogOff method works, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your logoff function you should clear any session variable. 
Instead of @HTML.ActionLink() try to use < a href="/Account/LogOff" >Log Off< /a >

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you saw it but my problem is solved, answer is in first post comments.
Anyway, thanks for the tip about clear session variables :)